# Cannot access AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

`Java` code is trying to put message in `AWS SQS`. But we are getting error

`AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-1.amzon.com/...... is denied Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 2fe34c11-7af8-5445-a768-070159a0953e`

There is no issue with the policy same policy works in test region but we are getting this error in dev.

I also tried with policy "sqs:*", but this is also not working.

`Java` application is running in `EC2` and we have given this role to `EC2`.

Also when I tried sending message through `AWSCLi` from the same `EC2` it works.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Please suggest.

We are using `proxy` to connect to `SQS` `URL` here. Incase if `proxy` is not working how it will try to resolve `URL` using `SQS` Endpoint?

Comment: Typo `amzon` in: `https://sqs.eu-west-1.amzon.com`?

Comment: @John Yes its typo as i use VDI machine and cannot do copy/paste.But queue name is correct.

Comment: What is the instance role?

Comment: @Marcin in INstance role policy we have given full access of sqs

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Are you sure that the Java application uses the Instance role? It does not use any hard codded credentials or aws profiles, nor runs in a container, or assumes some other role to call sqs?

Comment: @John We have used policy like ```"Sid": "Stmt1600355053476",
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:572205960066:Q-S3",
      "Principal": "*" ```

Comment: @Marcin yes they are using EC2 roles not harcoded values or aws profiles.

Comment: have you setup Proxy as per docutmetation here 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/section-client-configuration.html#proxy-configuration

When constructing a client object, you can pass in an optional ClientConfiguration object to customize the client’s configuration.

If you connect to the Internet through a proxy server, you’ll need to configure your proxy server settings (proxy host, port, and username/password) through the ClientConfiguration object.